# How to define facelets.Encoding in JSF2?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In JSF sources I found the logic of defining character encoding via facelets.Encoding attribute, which can be available in FacesContext.getAttributes()
See FaceletViewHandlingStrategy#getResponseEncoding method for details. How can I define this attribute for instance of FacesContext? I tried to define it via context-param in web.xml, but it's not working. And also I didn't find any reference about it in JSF documentation.

The main reason why I want do this, it is overriding of javax.faces.request.charset value. I don't want define a special filter for my application the order to define not UTF-8 encoding. Because my application contains a lot of WAR packages inside of big EAR.

Comment: You're not terribly clear on which problem exactly you're trying to solve this way, so it's hard to propose the answer you [really](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) need, but the normal way to define the view encoding is via `<f:view encoding="UTF-8">` whereby `UTF-8` is the default already. Give it a try and see if that indeed solves your problem. If not, then you need to elaborate more about the concrete problem than about the imagined solution which is not necessarily the right solution per se.

Comment: @BalusC `<f:view/>` it's exactly what I need, but with the other encoding value. But I have a lot of xhtml pages. So, I can't change them all. I need in global parameter, which can change default JSF encoding from UTF-8 to another, and I suppose that `facelets.Encoding` will help me.

Comment: So, you have a lot of copypasted XHTML files without a common master template? Well, then you've actually a different problem.

Comment: No, i have a lot of war packages with a lot of templates inside. And I can't apply `<f:view/>` for each of them. I want to do it globally. Does JSF support this possibility or not?
Why? Because JBoss / Tomcat uses ISO-8859-1 as default encoding and JSF uses UTF-8. When someone submits a form with umlauts then data inside will be broken. Solution with a special filter is working. But hold in memory, that after creation of new WAR module, I must add this filter, otherwise JSF will break a data, it is a bad solution. And we will getting bugs from time to time.

Comment: Note that server URI encoding is only used on GET request params, not on POST request params.

Comment: @BalusC in case of JBoss EAP 6, which we are using, it's not true. ISO-8859-1 is the default encoding for GET and POST requests. 
If I would changed value of `facelets.Encoding` JSF attribute, then it would solved my problem globally. That's why, I've started my question with this point.

Comment: Not by default in JSF. So either it's reconfigured, or you're using PrimeFaces or other component library which inspects the POST params before Facelets gets chance to set its default encoding.

Comment: @BalusC I'm using Richfaces, but analayzing Richfaces sources is the last what I want to do :) So I suppose that I have only one working solution - use a special filter. Damn encoding! It's like the old joke about 14 standards. Yeah?

Anyway, thank you for your replies!

Comment: A servlet filter which sets POST request body encoding before FacesServlet is triggered is indeed the canonical solution to this.